# sql with clause within a with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, with-clause

can i do something like this :

```
with t as 
    (
        with tt as
            ( 
                 select * from table 
            )
        SELECT * FROM tt
    )
select * from t
```

i willing to perform some logic on output of inner with clause & than again do some operations on output of the outer with clause.

any help will be appreciated ...
Thanks

note :- its just some simplified query that will resolve my problem in my actual query, which have nested with clause

Answer (score 39):

You can do something like this:

```
with t as 
(
    select * from table
),
tt as
( 
     select * from t
)
select * from tt
```

Comment: do u mean `select * from table` in 7th line ?

Answer (score 14):

No, you cannot *nest* CTE (Common Table Expression) but you can *chain* them:

```
with t as 
(
    select * from table 
),
tt as
( 
    select * from t
)
SELECT * FROM tt
```

Comment: in first clause i can write some select query ?

Comment: @objectWithoutClass: **SURE!** Just go ahead, try it!